# How can I have a "asJson" method be part of a case class using spray-json?

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json

I want to be able to create case classes in Scala using spray-json, but define an `asJson` method in the class , but I can't seem to figure out how. For example, I'd like to be able to do this:

```
case class Foo(bar: String) {
  def toJson: JsValue = ...
}
```

It would be easy enough to create an implicit JSON converter:

```
object JsonProtocols extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val fooFormat = jsonFormat1(Foo)
}
```

But as far as I know, this can only be done outside of the class. I would love to find a way of declaring a JSON format *and* convert to JSON within the class itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could imagine doing this:

```
scala> import spray.json._
import spray.json._

scala> case class Foo(bar: String) {
  def toJson:JsValue = JsObject( "bar" -> JsString(bar) )
}
defined class Foo

scala> Foo("bar").toJson
res2: spray.json.JsValue = {"bar":"bar"}
```

So far so good, but that doesn't fit into Spray's typeclass mechanism.  Spray's routing DSL, for example, would give you a type error if you then tried to convert a Foo to/from a JsValue (e.g. using the route `entity( as[Foo] ) { ... }` ).  Nor could the implicits they have already prepared for you, for types like List and Set, work with Foo:

```
scala> import DefaultJsonProtocol._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

scala> List(Foo("bar")).toJson
<console>:31: error: Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for List[Foo]
              List(Foo("bar")).toJson
```

because there is no JsonFormat class for them to use to convert a Foo, like the one that `JsonFormat1(Foo)` would have created.

You might then think to put the format inside the Foo companion object, since an in-scope class's companion object is on the implicit search path, like so:

```
object Foo extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val fooFormat = jsonFormat1(Foo)
}
case class Foo(bar: String)
```

But because we're not finished defining Foo at that point, the compiler gives us a type error:

```
[error]  found   : Foo.type
[error]  required: ? => ?
[error]  Note: implicit value fooFormat is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
```

Adding an explicit result type of `RootJsonFormat[Foo]` doesn't solve the problem:

```
[error]  found   : Foo.type
[error]  required: ? => Foo
[error]   implicit val fooFormat:RootJsonFormat[Foo] = jsonFormat1(Foo)
```

The trick (thanks knutwalker!) is to explicitly pass `Foo.apply`:

```
object Foo extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val fooFormat = jsonFormat1(Foo.apply)
}
case class Foo(bar: String)
```

Comment: The companion object is part of the implicit search scope. It's sufficient to define it in the companion, it will be found without the explicit import.

Comment: I can't seem to get that to work.  I tried creating a Foo object which extends DefaultJsonProtocol and contains `implicit val barFormat = jsonFormat1(Bar)`, but since I haven't finished defining Bar at that point the compiler is unhappy.  If you can make that work, you deserve the green check; I'll happily learn from your answer!

Comment: `Foo.apply` does the trick, that is, `implicit val barFormat = jsonFormat1(Foo.apply)`. I dropped it in a gist: https://gist.github.com/knutwalker/10355424